# Rails dataTable column search placement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

In a Rails app, I'm using `dataTables` and a `columnFilter.js`.

I want the column search to be at the top of the dataTable and not the bottom.

So, I added this in the js:

```
.columnFilter(
  sPlaceHolder: "head:before"
```

And I added a 2nd row to the header, like this:

```
<table class="display dataTable table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable1">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Search</th>
  <th>Search</th>
  <th>Search</th>
  <th>Search</th>
  <th>Search</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Desc</th>
  <th>Client</th>
  <th>Project</th>
  <th>Employee</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

It looks fine on my Mac:

[image]

But, on Heroku the table rows are switched:

[image]